# How do I make my discord bot play an audio file right when it joins a voice channel, like the airhorn solutions bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def joinvoice(ctx):
    """Joins user's voice channel"""
    author = ctx.message.author
    voice_channel = author.voice_channel
    vc = await client.join_voice_channel(voice_channel)
```

That is how I currently make the bot join a voice channel, how would I make it play an audio file as it joins? I have almost 0 experience, so far the entire bot has been coded by asking questions and a LOT of googling. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a StreamPlayer and use the player operations to play the audio. Heres some example code I wrote to play a vuvuzela with my discord bot:

```
@client.command(
    name='vuvuzela',
    description='Plays an awful vuvuzela in the voice channel',
    pass_context=True,
)
async def vuvuzela(context):
    # grab the user who sent the command
    user = context.message.author
    voice_channel = user.voice.voice_channel
    channel = None
    if voice_channel != None:
        channel = voice_channel.name
        await client.say('User is in channel: ' + channel)
        vc = await client.join_voice_channel(voice_channel)
        player = vc.create_ffmpeg_player('vuvuzela.mp3', after=lambda: print('done'))
        player.start()
        while not player.is_done():
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        player.stop()
        await vc.disconnect()
    else:
        await client.say('User is not in a channel.')
```